# pig latin Could not resolve STRSPLIT using imports:

Tags: apache-pig

I ma getting the following error when using STRSPLIT in my local script

```
Could not resolve STRSPLIT using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

i am running pig on my local system and executing via -x local.

how do i get the right imports for STRSPLIT?

**EDIT**

Here is the script i am using

```
A0 = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(flash_version, '_')) as (major:int, minor:int), userid,  resH, resW;
```

Pig version

Apache Pig version 0.7.0 (r941408)

Comment: Can you post your PigScript?

Comment: Please share your pigscript.

Comment: Which pig version are you using? As far as I know pig 7 has no STRSPLIT

Comment: I have the same issue with REPLACE,

Comment: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve REPLACE using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]